# How to dynamically resize a highslide popup called from a Highchart graph using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, highcharts, highslide

Below is the section of jquery code where the highslide popup is called - hs.htmlExpand(). I want to be able to resize the popup dynamically. If this is not possible, maybe auto resize would work for me. The reason I want to resize dynamically is because the text within the popup will change dynamically as well.

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {

           hs.htmlExpand(null, {
              pageOrigin: {
                   x: this.pageX,
                   y: this.pageY
              },
              headingText: 'Error Rate',
              maincontentText: 'test',
              width: 220
            });
     }
  }
}, ...
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpa/1200/

I have come across the following code in the Highslide documentation but I don't know how to use it in this context:

```
void hs.Expander.prototype.resizeTo ( int width, int height )
void hs.Expander.prototype.reflow()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `hs.getExpander()`, it'll return the last opened expander.  Then you can use:

```
var ex = hs.getExpander();
ex.resizeTo(600,600);
```

`reflow()` worked well with updated content:

```
var ex = hs.getExpander();
ex.maincontent.innerHTML = "alkdfjalkdjf<br/>laksjdflaksjdf<br/>asjkdf<br/>lajkdf<br/>asjkdfl<br/>aksjdflkasjdflk<br/>ajsdfl<br/>kjasdfl<br/>kjasdfkl";
ex.reflow();
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpa/1201/).

Comment: Exactly what I needed plus the reflow(). Thank you so much. You are awesome!